# Add more data to rendered block

Tags: magento2, php, checkout

I found a code to render a block at `overview.phtml` like code below.

overview.phtml:

```
<?php echo $block->getRowItemHtml($_item); ?>
```

And here's the `Overview.php` for it.

Overview.php:

```
/**
     * Return row-level item html
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $item
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRowItemHtml(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $item)
    {
        $type = $this->_getItemType($item);
        $renderer = $this->_getRowItemRenderer($type)->setItem($item);
        $this->_prepareItem($renderer);
        return $renderer->toHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve renderer block for row-level item output
     *
     * @param string $type
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock
     */
    protected function _getRowItemRenderer($type)
    {
        $renderer = $this->getItemRenderer($type);
        if ($renderer !== $this->getItemRenderer(self::DEFAULT_TYPE)) {
            $renderer->setTemplate($this->getRowRendererTemplate());
        }
        return $renderer;
    }
```

And the code from `Overview.php` is pass to `item.phtml` for overview page. So my question is, i got data like `'id'` that i want to pass to `item.phtml` from `overview.phtml`, how can i pass it from the `Overview.php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass custom data to `item.phtml` by using magento magic methods to set data to `$_item`, like this

**overview.phtml**

```
<?php $customData = 15 ?>
<?php foreach ($block->getShippingAddressItems($_address) as $_item): ?>
    <?php echo $block->getRowItemHtml($_item->setCustomData($customData));?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**item.phtml**

```
<?php $_item = $block->getItem() ?>
<?php $customData = $_item->getCustomData() ?>
```